# How to only allow to boot from cd?

Tags: boot, live-cd

I want to boot from live cd but I can't get anything to work. Only goes to HDD. Tried all the buttons at startup. Is there a way to ONLY boot from cd drive?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information?  You can't get into a boot priority menu OR the BIOS settings at boot?  Keep in mind the keys for this are motherboard-specific.  Or can you set the priority, but it doesn't boot from CD as requested anyway?

Comment: do you know how to get into bios?

Comment: Im running on a ppc g4. and no I cant get to a priority menu.

Comment: I got the right live disc that supports ppc also.

Comment: I'm not too sure whether this is your system type. But a quick google search showed me; [**Powerbook G4 (PPC): Cannot boot from disc to install**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1405442&p=8827332#post8827332)

Comment: I have the mac mini G4. I got it to install Ubuntu 6.10 and its working, but I think it might be corrupted so I want to start fresh.

Comment: did you open your bios?

Comment: At startup try the following key combo for a PPC G4 Command-Option-Shift-Delete this will bypass the device that is selected in the Startup Disk control panel; boot from the first bootable device other than that. Also try the following Boot in open firmware ( Command+Option+O+F )
enter boot hd:,\install\yaboot

Comment: Not sure if this is pertinent to PPC G4 but another option is to hold down the 'C' key as you turn the power on. Once you hear the CD drive reading the disk you can release the key.

Answer (score 0):

**For a PPC**

At startup try the following key combo for a PPC G4 `Command-Option-Shift-Delete` this will bypass the device that is selected in the Startup Disk control panel; boot from the first bootable device other than that.

You can also try to boot in open firmware Command+Option+O+F
then enter boot hd:,\install\yaboot

This should then allow you to boot the CD using yaboot

Not sure if this is pertinent to PPC G4 but another option is to hold down the 'C' key as you turn the power on. Once you hear the CD drive reading the disk you can release the key.

**For a PC**

When your computer first comes on hit the Delete key or F2 or F12 key a few times, to launch into the BIOS (This step might be different from machine to machine). Inside this screen look for Boot order or maybe Boot Sequence and set the first device in the list to the CD-ROM device.

For example the screen shown below you would use the Delete key, take note of which key your BIOS requires you to press.

[image: POST Screen - First Boot]

Then the BIOS screen may look something like these the first is an Award BIOS where you would navigate to Advance BIOS Features the second is a Pheonix BIOS where you would navigate to the Boot tab. Again the screens you see may vary depending on your motherboard manufacturer. With both of the BIOS variants listed you would use the + and - keys to change the value of the First Boot Device, then key F10 to Save in the case of the Award BIOS and Save and Exit in the Phoenix BIOS.

[image: Award BIOS Change Boot Order]

[image: Phoenix BIOS Change Boot Order]